# UniqueEntity with two (many) fields is not working

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-validator

I have a problem related to using Symphony (v5.4) with API Platform based on PHP 8.1.

I have an entity called `Customer` which has `email`, `phoneNumber` fields that are unique per `tenantId` (two fields per unique db index).

Part of the Doctrine mapping (XML) re. to these indexes:

```xml
<unique-constraints>
            <unique-constraint columns="tenant_id,email" name="unique_customer_email"/>
            <unique-constraint columns="tenant_id,phone_number" name="unique_customer_phone_number"/>
</unique-constraints>
```

Also, the entity has `UniqueEntity` annotation (`use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;`) like below

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Modules\RentalCustomers\Application\Query;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use App\Shared\Address\Address;
use App\Shared\Email\Email;
use App\Shared\Email\Serializer\EmailNormalizer;
use App\Shared\TaxNumber\TaxNumber;
use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumber;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;
use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Context;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'security_get_denormalize' => "is_granted('CUSTOMER_VIEW', object)",
        ],
        'post' => [
            'security_post_denormalize' => "is_granted('CUSTOMER_CREATE', object)",
        ],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'normalization_context' => [
                'groups' => [
                    'customer:read',
                    'with:address',
                ],
            ],
            'security' => "is_granted('CUSTOMER_VIEW', object)",
        ],
        'put' => [
            'normalization_context' => [
                'groups' => [
                    'customers:write',
                    'with:address',
                ],
            ],
            'security' => "is_granted('CUSTOMER_UPDATE', object)",
        ],
    ],
    attributes: [
        'validation_groups' => [self::class, 'validationGroups'],
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => [
            'customers:write',
            'with:address',
        ],
    ],
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => [
            'customers:read',
            'with:address',
        ],
    ],
    routePrefix: '/rental-customers',
)]
#[UniqueEntity(['tenantId', 'email'], null, null, null, null, null, 'email')]
#[UniqueEntity(['tenantId', 'phoneNumber'], null, null, null, null, null, 'phoneNumber')]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['lastName' => 'partial', 'email' => 'partial', 'phoneNumber' => 'partial'])]
class Customer
{
    #[ApiProperty(writable: false, identifier: true)]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    public UuidInterface $id;

    #[ApiProperty(writable: true, required: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['company', 'Default'])]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    public ?string $companyName;

    #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['company', 'Default'])]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    #[ApiProperty(
        writable: true,
        required: true,
        attributes: [
            'openapi_context' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'example' => '542453244242',
            ],
        ]
    )]
    public ?TaxNumber $companyTaxNumber;

    #[ApiProperty(required: true)]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['person', 'Default'])]
    public string $firstName;

    #[ApiProperty(required: true)]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['person', 'Default'])]
    public string $lastName;

    /**
     * @AssertPhoneNumber
     */
    #[ApiProperty(
        attributes: [
            'openapi_context' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'example' => '+48500600700',
            ],
        ]
    )]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    public PhoneNumber $phoneNumber;

    #[ApiProperty(
        required: true,
        attributes: [
            'openapi_context' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'example' => 'api@renthelp.io',
            ],
        ]
    )]
    #[Assert\Email, Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Context([EmailNormalizer::class])]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    public Email $email;

    #[Assert\NotNull(groups: ['person', 'Default']), Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['person', 'Default'])]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    public string $nationalIdentificationNumber;

    #[ApiSubresource]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read'])]
    public Collection $documents;

    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:write', 'customers:read'])]
    #[ORM\Embedded(Address::class, 'address_')]
    public Address $address;

    #[ApiProperty(readable: false, writable: false)]
    public UuidInterface $tenantId;

    #[ApiProperty(writable: false)]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    public DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Groups(['customer:read', 'customers:read', 'customers:write'])]
    #[ApiProperty(
        writable: true,
        required: true,
        attributes: [
            'openapi_context' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'example' => 'person or company',
            ],
        ]
    )]
    public CustomerType $type;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'email' => $this->email->value(),
            'firstName' => $this->firstName,
            'lastName' => $this->lastName,
            'phoneNumber' => $this->phoneNumber->getRawInput(),
            'address' => $this->address->toArray(),
            'nationalIdentificationNumber' => $this->nationalIdentificationNumber,
            'type' => (string) $this->type,
            'companyName' => $this->companyName ?? '',
            'companyTaxNumber' => $this->companyTaxNumber !== null ? (string) $this->companyTaxNumber : '',
        ];
    }

    public static function validationGroups(self $customer): array
    {
        if ($customer->type->isCompany()) {
            return ['Default', 'company'];
        }

        return ['Default', 'person'];
    }
}
```

And... Symfony is not catching the constraint violation. It only works when I have an index on a single column, not for more (like here, for two). The endpoint is returning an exception (based on PostgreSQL) instead of 422 status code with a field-related conflict error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate
 key value violates unique constraint "unique_customer_email" DETAIL:  Key (tenant_id, email)=(99ca30b3-56e6-4177-87a1-f5bd6e956ea4, test@test.com) already exists."
```

Any ideas? I was googling this problem a few times in a row, and still I'm here...

Worth adding is that I have objects for thoese fields like: `PhoneNumber`, `Email` and `TenantId`, they are not scalars! BUT, for a single field it works, so I assume that's not the problem.

I was trying to use different order of these fields. I was also trying to specyfiy `errorPath` but that's something different... :(

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the code that is processing the Form and the entities, along with all of their related constraints. eg: `Assert\Valid`, `Assert\Email`, etc.

Comment: Sure, it's done. But I think it will not help, it's a mess now.

Comment: My guess is that the [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) are out of sync with intentions.  Check the debug of the submission to validate which group is being validated and ensure they align with your expectations. Also, as argument specifications change through versions, I'd also recommend using `#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['prop', 'prop'], errorPath: 'prop', groups: ['group'])]` syntax, as opposed to the explicit `null` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a complete solution, but things that might be helpful to consider:

UniqueEntity and the doctrine unique constraints are *different* things that have nothing to do with each other.

The *UniqueEntity* is a validator, that relies on the entity repository trying to fetch all entities that match the criteria. If no entity matching the criteria is found (or only the one that is actually being validated) validation will be passed, if a different entity with the given criteria is actually found, the validation will fail. From the docs:

> **repositoryMethod**:
> The name of the repository method used to determine the uniqueness. If
> it's left blank, findBy() will be used. The method receives as its
> argument a fieldName => value associative array (where fieldName is
> each of the fields configured in the fields option).
> https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

The *unique constraint* on the other hand is creating a real unique index in the database table. That's why you get the exception you mentioned.

I'd suggest you just step into

`Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityValidator::validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)`

espacially line 137:

`$result = $repository->{$constraint->repositoryMethod}($criteria)`

to see why the repository is not able to fetch the conflicting entity.